# Android - Perform an action with voice command

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, voice-recognition

Searched through the internet and couldn't find a god example of achieving the following. There is a Launcher activity. User will be navigated to the launcher activity first and inside that activity , when the user says a certain word like "Start" or something like that the app should navigate the user to another activity. I've gone through a set of tutorials , and I've seen some similar questions at SO but none of them make sense to me. What will be the best approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is

- build a framework/module to handle Speech Input ([speech-2-text](https://www.google.de/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&ei=LnWNWqqRGIzWkwW7wLyQDg&q=android%20speech%20to%20text%20tutorial&oq=android%20speech%20to%20text%20&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i203k1j0l2j0i203k1l7.7196.7196.0.10719.1.1.0.0.0.0.94.94.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.94....0.WbtHYps9NMk))

  - Depending on Input by user, perform an action